# Rendering view for object passed by {{link-to}} helper issue

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a simple list of animals showing them in categories.
When a category is picked in the nav all the animals from that category are listed along with their attributes.
When an animal-box is clicked a view for the animal is loaded. In it the category is eliminated and it is presented as animal generally.
That logic is implemented in my **routes**.

Here's the problem however the **animal route** doesn't bring the animal representation object to the view.

Can't get the animal although I pass the object `{{#link-to 'animal' this}}`

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your kind help.

Here's a:

**demo**: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sekuvabi/1

**full code mockup**: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sekuvabi/1/edit

**View**:

```
//......

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="cats">
    <h3>Cats</h3>
    <div class="nodec" style="display: table; border-spacing:20px;">
        {{#each cat in model}}
            {{#link-to 'animal' this}}
            <div class="box">
                <dl class="fsize15 resetstyle">
                    <h4>{{cat.name}}</h4>
                    <dt class="b fleft">Size:</dt>
                    <dd class="fleft">{{cat.specs.size}}</dd>
                    <dt class="b fleft clear">Speed:</dt>
                    <dd class="fleft">{{cat.specs.speed}}</dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
            {{/link-to}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="animal">
    <h3>Animal</h3>
    <div>
        <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </script>
```

**Script**:

```
//....

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("animals", function(){
    this.resource("cats");
  });
  this.route("animal",{path: 'animal/:animal_id'});
});

App.CatsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var cats = [];
    var animals = getJson();
    for(var place in animals.cats){
      $.merge(cats, animals.cats[place]);
    }
    return cats;
  }
});

App.AnimalRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('animal', params.animal_id);
  }
});

//......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `{{#link-to 'animal' cat}}` instead of `{{#link-to 'animal' this}}`:

Demo: http://jsbin.com/sekuvabi/2/

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="cats">
    <h3>Cats</h3>
    <div class="nodec" style="display: table; border-spacing:20px;">
        {{#each cat in model}}
            {{#link-to 'animal' cat}}
            <div class="box">
                <dl class="fsize15 resetstyle">
                    <h4>{{cat.name}}</h4>
                    <dt class="b fleft">Size:</dt>
                    <dd class="fleft">{{cat.specs.size}}</dd>
                    <dt class="b fleft clear">Speed:</dt>
                    <dd class="fleft">{{cat.specs.speed}}</dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
            {{/link-to}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
  </script>
```

Why `cat` and `not` this?

if you use the `{{ log }}` handle bar helper you'll see:

```
{{ log this }}
{{ log cat }}
```

that `this` is a reference to the class while `cat` is a reference to object. In this case you want to pass the object to link to so ember can pull the correct property off it and link to the correct route with in your nested resource.

Comment: Thank you very helpful. Appreciate it.